# How to mount disk.root into my new Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, mount, wubi, disk

I tried `sudo mount -t /media/66CC2BC0CC2B88FF/ubuntu/disks/disk.root -o ro,loop=/dev/loop0`
 but it didn't work. Any suggestions? TY!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish and why. The command and its arguments you typed doesn't make any sense, so it is not strange it doesn't work.

Comment: i try to mount a file disk.root(my previous wubi) to be able to browse it directly from my new clean installation(not wubi)

Comment: The `-t` option specifies the filesystem type, but you haven't supplied any. This is not usually required, but if you use `-t` you have to specify `ext3` or `ext4` or `auto`. From the man page: "`If no -t option is given, or if the auto type is specified, mount will try to guess the desired type.`" If `mount` cannot detect the filesystem type then it's probably corrupted and you'll need to fsck it. You don't need to specify the loop device either, although you can. `Jase`'s answer is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following command to mount your virtual disk:

```
mount -o loop /media/66CC2BC0CC2B88FF/ubuntu/disks/disk.root /mnt
```

After running that, the files from your wubi installation should be available in `/mnt`

Comment: 10x it worked perfectly!